# Configure Angular to 'ng lint' on file save

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint, tslint

I set up a custom `tslint.json` config and it works correctly.

When I use `ng start`, I just can see `tsc` (TypeScript compiler) errors output. But I also want to see tslint errors too. I don't want to explicitily have to execute `ng lint`. I wanna see `tslint` errors during development, on file save.

I know that I can include that `ng lint` on CI process, but I don't like that way.

I had looked for a lot, but I haven't found anything yet.

Is there any simple way like Vue does ?

Thanks!

Comment: Just add a script in the package.json `"lint_and_start": "ng lint && ng start"`.

Comment: @mamichels If you read the title of the question you see that I want it on file save / change.

Comment: Than you should check out your IDE. For JetBrains IDEs it is an ease to include your projects tslint.json for your 'live linting'.

Comment: @mamichels I don't want to use IDEs plugin. I want it to be restrictive for the project as security. I've found a solution I put in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I found a clean way. I installed with npm https://github.com/typicode/husky.

Husky let me declare a pre-commit hook in which I include `npm run lint`. If lint fails, it throws an error.